# Where is a value type object stored in swift?

Tags: swift

I declared an object of Array, like:

```
let data = ["foo", "bar"]
```

Array type in swift is value type, where is it stored? heap or stack?

I guess it is stored in heap, but how to access it?

And does it follow ARC rule, when will it release?

Can you give me the graphic of the object's memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift or other language, by default, Value type is stored in Stack and Reference Type is stored in Heap.

If the value is part of a reference type, then, it's stored in Heap.

So we don't need a reference counting and the value will be clean after the end of its scope, or in the other case, when the container is released.

In your example: the data of `Array` instance will be stored in Stack of the Application while its elements can be stored in Heap, depend on the element is reference type or value typed.

Comment: There won't be any elements in the array. It was declared as constant ;)

Comment: That's so true ^^

Comment: Thx, I got it!  ^^

Answer (score 3):

Given the empty array:

```
let data = Array<Any>()
```

> Array type in swift is value type, where is it stored? heap or stack?

This is a constant, empty array, so it is stored nowhere. Literally nowhere. If it had some elements in it, the boxes for them would be stored on the stack. The contents of those boxes might be stored on the stack or heap depending on the size. If it had more elements, the boxes would also be stored on the heap.

> And does it follow ARC rule, when will it release?

Value types are destroyed when their referent goes out of scope, so whenever `data` leaves scope. ARC is not relevant here. That said, if there are other reference of the backing (heap) storage, then that storage may not be destroyed until later and ARC is totally relevant (but completely internal, so not related to `data`).

> Can you give me the graphic of the object's memory?

In the case given, the graphic of object memory is:

---

---

That's it. There is no memory. But if you put things in it, then it would wildly depend on what you put it in it.

I know I'm being incredibly flippant here. That's on purpose. The answer is "it depends, and also, in most cases, you shouldn't care, and in all cases, it's an internal implementation detail that is not promised and can change from release to release."

The time where you *do* care is when there's a performance concern, and then you care a lot. Unfortunately, Swift gives almost no promises about that. Even so, we do have a lot of specific information from the Swift team. The best resource is [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) from WWDC 2016 which explains the internal memory layout. It is likely nothing like you're expecting, and it is incredibly dependent on the specifics of the array. Given the array you've asked about, the answer is "nowhere; it's empty."

Comment: Sorry, my sample is inappropriate, because I am focus on the value type, not it's contents. Now I was a little understood, it depends on the type of it's contents or elements. And there is no about reference, it's value, so it is unrelated with ARC.

Comment: Even if the Array is empty, still there is memory required for storing its metadata. You can read swift source code here. https://github.com/apple/swift/